# How to find the number of distinct values in a column with SQL

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have 3 tables:

> customer_table(customer_id, customer_name)

> product_table(product_id, product_name)

> purchase_table(product_id, customer_id)

And I want to find the `customer_id` and the number of different types of products purchased by the this customer.

This is what I have so far but it's incorrect

```sql
select c.customer_id
    from customer_table c;
union
select count(distinct product_id)
    from purchase_table
        where customer_id = c.customer id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select c.customer_id,
    (select count(distinct product_id)
         from purchase_table
             where customer_id = c.customer id) as count_product
    from customer_table c;
```